# TortoiseCVS. Being asked for a paasword while doing a Checkout on Windows 7

Tags: tortoisecvs

M y apologies if this question has been asked before, if it has been point me to the answer and I will remove this.

I use TortoiseCSV version 1.12.5 in conjuction woth an ssh server, I have created the keys and I can logon the Unix box we use as the CVS repository ok - with out typing in the password - which proves that the key works.

My problem occurs when I go to a Checkout for the first time. I get asked for the TortoiseCVS password. I try the password and key pharase both to the Unix box and neither work.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Rob..

Comment: You shall ask the question at Super User forum [http://superuser.com/]

Comment: will do thanks very much